# Post file to server - Swift

Tags: html, swift, upload, server, http-post

First off, I know, there are a lot of questions on this topic, but I still don't get it.

Inside my iOS app, I want to post a string to a file on my server. I found many ways to do that online and went with the following:

```
func postBookingNumber() {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myServerURL.com/booking-number.txt")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "date=\(Date())&booking-number=\(self.getBookingNumber())" //returns string with format: "01"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now, the file on the server is currently emtpy, until I post something to it. My plan was to either append the new booking number string to the file, **OR** downloading the file, appending the new booking number string to it and replacing the online version with the one I just edited inside my app.

#### Questions

1. Does the code above & my strategy make any sense?
2. How do I handle the `"date=\(Date())&booking-number=\(self.getBookingNumber())"` request on the server side?
   Can I go with HTML or do I have to use JS? PHP?

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to server stuff, so please be kind :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that doesn't work that way (but i never tried:) ). You're supposed to have something that parses your POST request and writes file where it's needed. But again, I've never even thought to do it that way :)

Comment: Ok so how would you go about this task? Could you provide some code?